# Handling parameterised routes in express-jwt using unless

Tags: express, express-jwt

Given the following route:

```
router.get('/api/members/confirm/:id, function (req, res, next)
```

how do I specify the route to be excluded? I have tried:

```
app.use('/api', expressJwt({ secret: config.secret}).unless({path: ['/api/members/confirm']}));
```

and

```
app.use('/api', expressJwt({ secret: config.secret}).unless({path: ['/api/members/confirm/:id']}));
```

but neither path in the unless array seem to work?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `express-jwt` module is using [express-unless](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-unless) to give you this `unless` method, which doesn't accept express' `:param` path arguments syntax.

But it does accept a regex, so you could do this:

```
app.use('/api', expressJwt({ secret: config.secret}).unless({path: [/^\/api\/members\/confirm\/.*/]}));
```

If you don't like that, you can also give unless a function:

```
var myFilter = function(req) {return true;}
app.use('/api', expressJwt({ secret: config.secret}).unless(myFilter));
```

Answer (score 15):

You must be using regex to achieve what you are looking for, and you can also add in another field to specify what methods are allowed like so:

```
expressJwt({ secret, isRevoked }).unless({
    path: [
        { url: /^\/api\/members\/confirm\/.*/, methods: ['GET', 'PUT'] }
    ]
})
```